# mysql rows are deleted by themself

Tags: php, mysql

I am developing a web application based on php/laravel. It is about to finish and we are testing it nowadays. But there is a problem with mysql table. 
I have a table called follows.If someone follows another, I create a record on this table. There is no problem here but periodically records on this table is deleted and it is not triggered by user who doesn't want to follow someone. Or there is no intervention by system admin. Even more, I have 20+ tables and just follows table has this problem.

I checked my codes and I couldn't find any reason what causes this problem. I inspected mysql table on phpmyadmin and again I couldn't see anything wrong. Now Can you say 'there is something like that and causes this problem'? Or how can I debug this problem on mysql? Is it good trying to go for triggers? I need to find what is causing this problem.
There is no more I have to say, and I am about to go crazy..

Please write down what do you need to here extra that I forget to write here..

Comment: There is no way those entries vanish all by themselves. I am afraid there is nothing we can help with, all we could say would be _guess work_.

Comment: Could be a trigger issue. may be a `AFTER INSERT` trigger which is doing this

Comment: phpmyadmin says 'There are no triggers to display.'. Is there a way to put breakpoint to delete query? or can i log which query executed by whom

Comment: You've got yourself a murder mystery here. Read some Agatha Christie and get to work solving it.

Comment: I would actually add triggers to your table (for inserts, deletes and updates) that write every change to a history table (with current time), so once you miss an entry, you maybe can pinpoint it to some other event or at least a time (or check if it maybe didn't get inserted when you thought it would). Enable mysql query logs, so you can find out  what querys were executed at that moment. You probably just unintentionally execute some code in laravel.